# AWS CF Is it possible to extract or export InstanceID from ASG or userdata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there anyway how to extract or export InstanceID from ASG or UserData so I can pass it as variable in Resources for example ${InstanceID}? I have a CF NFS template for a service, basically for resources it creates asg, cloudwatch dashboard, volume, security group, launch template.

So the thing is I need the InstanceID for my CloudWatch widget, otherwise it won't find the correct one.
In UserData I have a way how to get instanceid INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://ip/latest/meta-data/instance-id) now I need to find a way how to get it outside userdata.

I have tried to !GetAtt from Asg but it seems that doesn't work

Comment: Could you provide more information about the CloudWatch widget? If you are constructing this widget with CloudFormation, what AWS::CloudWatch::??? resource are you using? I suspect that you can use something other than Instance Id to create the CloudWatch widget.

Comment: As an example
          {
            "type":"metric",
            "x":12,
            "y":7,
            "width":12,
            "height":6,
            "properties":{
              "metrics":[
                ["CWAgent","disk_used_percent","path","data/bitbucket-home","InstanceId","${InstanceID}","AutoScalingGroupName","${Asg}","device","nvme1n1","fstype","ext4"]
              ],
              "title":"${Environment} Bitbucket NFS Free Disk Space",
              "period":300,
              "region":"eu-west-1",
              "stat": "Minimum"
            }
          }

Comment: For example if I try to manually add the widget CWAgent it shows multiple results even with instance id's that are terminated, so I somehow need to narrow search to the current instanceid.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible without a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) for the extraction of instance id from ASG.

Comment: With that you mean that I have to add InstacneID as a parameter in my template?

Comment: @user21281320 No. You have to develop your own custom resource. Please read docs I linked on what custom resources are.